# How can I return differents html columns in different html rows in a while loop with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop

My trouble is probably easy to solve for you, but despite attempts, I was unable to solve.
I would like to return all database values subdiveded per row and column. I'll explain easier:
I would like to enter a maximum of four columns and as many rows as records divided by columns.
Example:

```
<div class="row categorie" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=1"><img src="img/slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Cucine</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=2"><img src="img/slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Soggiorni</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=3"><img src="img/slide3.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Divani</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=4"><img src="img/slide4.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Bagni</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row categorie" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=5"><img src="img/slide5.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Tavoli e sedie</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=6"><img src="img/slide6.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Camere</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=7"><img src="img/slide7.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
        <p class="nome">Accessori</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I would like to obtain. But the code returns a single row instead of two.
This is the code i wrote:

```
<div class="row categorie" style="margin:0; padding: 0;">
<?php $query = "SELECT * FROM categorie";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 no-padding">
        <div class="categoria"><a href="offerte.php?s=<?= $row[0]; ?>"><img src="img/slide<?= $row[0]; ?>.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
        <p class="nome"><?= $row[1]; ?></p></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch.........)
          $results[] = $row;


 foreach(array_chunk($results, 4)
        as $row)){
    echo '<div class = "row-with-4-items">';   

   foreach($row as $item)
         print_r($item);

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I can't use your code because I have to pass mysql parameters to html code ($row[0])....

Comment: But with this code, the last three elements will be lost?